# Python itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have 4 lists with a different number of elements. I would like to output all possible combinations of 3 items of the individual list elements.
One approach is the itertool.combinations (), but with .combinations I can only combine the items within a list.

Lists:

```
colors      = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "black", "magenta"]
numbers     = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
material = ["beton", "wood", "stone"]
names      = ["Susi", "Klara", "Claire", "Moni"]
```

Result should be:

```
[blue, 1, beton], [blue, 1, Susi], [blue, 2, beton]…
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried

Comment: so basically you want to combine material & names? because it's not clear with your expected output

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `product()`:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(colors, numbers, material + names))
```

Comment: I don't think OP has asked for combining materials and names. I think the source of that confusion is that in the expected output, OP has mentioned only a few combos, and by chance, names do not figure in those combos.

Answer (score 1):

Use `product`, and `chain` names and material:

```
from itertools import chain, product

colors      = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "black", "magenta"]
numbers     = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
material = ["beton", "wood", "stone"]
names      = ["Susi", "Klara", "Claire", "Moni"]

out = product(colors, numbers, chain(material, names))
```

A part of the output:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(next(out))

('blue', 1, 'beton')
('blue', 1, 'wood')
('blue', 1, 'stone')
('blue', 1, 'Susi')
('blue', 1, 'Klara')
('blue', 1, 'Claire')
('blue', 1, 'Moni')
('blue', 2, 'beton')
('blue', 2, 'wood')
('blue', 2, 'stone')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to combine items from different lists is `itertools.product` and what you need to choose 3 lists from a set of four lists is `itertools.combinations`.

I provide a *simplified*, *shortened* example of the application of these two tools below:

```
In [57]: from itertools import product, combinations                                      

In [58]: a, b, c = ['stone','concrete'], ['Jane','Mary'], [1,2,3]                         

In [59]: for l1, l2 in combinations((a,b,c), 2): 
    ...:     for i1, i2 in product(l1,l2): 
    ...:         print(i1, i2)                                                            
stone Jane
stone Mary
concrete Jane
concrete Mary
stone 1
stone 2
stone 3
concrete 1
concrete 2
concrete 3
Jane 1
Jane 2
Jane 3
Mary 1
Mary 2
Mary 3

In [60]:
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work, producing 436 combinations:

```
import itertools as itls

colors      = ["blue", "yellow", "green", "black", "magenta"]
numbers     = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
material    = ["beton", "wood", "stone"]
names       = ["Susi", "Klara", "Claire", "Moni"]

my_lists    = [colors, numbers, material, names]

my_combos = [(x,y,z) for (lst_1,lst_2,lst_3) in itls.combinations(my_lists,3) 
                             for (x,y,z) in itls.product(lst_1, lst_2, lst_3) ]

# print (my_combos)
print (len(my_combos))
```

**Explanation:**

The required result is constructed as a list, and assigned to `my_combos`.

The list is constructed using a list comprehension that has a nested double iteration.

In the nested double iteration:

1. The outer for loop `for (lst_1,lst_2,lst_3) in itls.combinations(my_lists,3)` iterates over all possible combinations of lists, taking 3 lists at a time.
2. The inner for loop `for (x,y,z) in itls.product(lst_1, lst_2, lst_3)` iterates over a cartesian product of `lst_1`, `lst_2`, and `lst_3` (these `lst_1`, `lst_2`, and `lst_3` get defined for each iteration of the outer for loop)

Code to verify that there are no duplicates in the result:

```
# Code to verify that there are no duplicates.
from collections import Counter
for x, count_x in counts.items():
    if (count_x > 1): # if duplicate
        print ("Duplicate item ({}) occurs {} times".format(x, count_x))
```

Comment: Very complicated solution. I will upvote if you explain all steps.

Comment: @MykolaZotko, added explanation.

Comment: I think you will get duplicates like `[blue, 1, beton]` and `[beton, 1, blue]`. You get permutations.

Comment: @MykolaZotko, the duplicates you mentioned would occur only if `permutations` is used instead of `combinations`. In any case, a manual computation confirms that 436 is the correct number of combinations to be expected, and that's what this gives too.

Comment: What I need is a combination of all items in the lists, no matter in which order the lists are. Prerequisite is: there must be any 3 items from 4 lists, and no duplicates may occur.
#fountainhead: here are some duplicates
#Mykola Zotko: that's right, it's just coincidence that names do not occur in my example

Comment: @Tom, No, there aren't any duplicate combinations in the result. To help you verify that, I've updated my answer providing a code snippet that would print out the duplicates if any. I ran the code, and found no duplicates. Also, if you manually calculate the combinations that will be generated, you get the number 436, and that's exactly how many combinations I got.

Comment: @Tom: My understanding of your problem is that, you need to to select 3 lists at a time, out of the 4 lists. (There are 4 ways of doing that). For each such selection of lists, the cartesian product of the 3 lists needs to be generated. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Tom: Please give me examples of duplicates that you *actually* found to be generated from my code.